# Comparing values of each element in a list with every other element within the list and updating it (f#)

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, collision-detection

I am currently trying to learn F# and I am attempting to make a very simple game played in the console. I am trying to get some rudimentary collision detection up and running which I planned to work as such:

Each element with a specific tag within the game object list would be iterated upon and if another element in the game object list was found to share the same coordinate as the first object, the first object would be put back in its old position.

So the type is something like this:

```
type Object = {
x : int;
y : int;
model : char;
}
```

And every object in the game uses this type in a game object list (objects have a update method etc.) However when trying to do collision detection I am struggling with an approach as none of the default list operations really work and I am assuming I need to somehow pattern match for the specific tag and then iterate through the list again checking for a match in coordinates?

Any ideas or pointers or help of any sort would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what you want to do, but the following example should give you some idea.

I'm assuming you have `objects`, which is a list of all objects of the game. This includes one object with a given `model` value that you want to move. The following function gets `modelToMove` as an argument (to identify the object that should be moved) together with new X and Y coordinates for the object and a list of all objects.

If there is something at the new X and Y coordinates, it just returns the original objects. Otherwise, it moves the object with the given `model` to the new location:

```
let moveObject modelToMove (newX, newY) objects = 
  let blocked = objects |> List.exists (fun o -> o.x = newX && o.y = newY)
  if blocked then objects 
  else  
    objects |> List.map (fun o ->
      if o.model = modelToMove then { o with x = newX; y = newY }
      else o)
```

To check if a position is blocked, we use `List.exists`. To create a list with new updated object positions, we use `List.map`.

Comment: Thanks, my explanation of the problem was not exactly great, apologies but this was pretty much exactly the type of approach I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that something along these lines will do:

```
type GameObjectType =
    | Player
    | Bullet
    | Wall
    // etc.

type Position =
    {
        x : int
        y : int
    }

type GameObject =
    {
        objectType : GameObjectType
        position : Position
    }

type Rectangle = Position * Position // rectagle is defined by two opposite corners.

type IntersectionResult =
    | NoIntersection
    | Rectangle of Rectangle

type CollisionHandler =
    {
        intersect : GameObject -> GameObject -> IntersectionResult
        handleCollision : (GameObject * GameObject) -> Rectangle -> (GameObject * GameObject)
    }

let handleCollisions (handler : CollisionHandler) (objects : List<GameObject>) =
    // Handle collision of two objects a and b.
    let handleCollision (a, b) =
        match handler.intersect a b with
        | NoIntersection -> (a, b)
        | Rectangle r -> handler.handleCollision (a, b) r

    // Handle collision of object a with the list c by iterating through
    // the list and updating position of object a and current element of the list r.
    let handleCollisions (a, c) =
        c
        |> List.fold (fun acc r -> 
                        let (n, m) = handleCollision (fst acc, r)
                        (n, m :: (snd acc))
                        ) (a, [])

    let rec inner processed remaining =

        match remaining with
        | [] -> processed
        | h :: t ->
            let (newH, newT) = handleCollisions (h, t)
            inner (newH :: processed) newT

    inner [] objects
```

You will need to provide functions to determine collisions: `intersect` and how to handle them: `handleCollision` in the `CollisionHandler`.